# PDF merge should be done by user when I add security for admin by PDFsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am adding security to PDF using PDFsharp.

This is my code for adding Owner password:

```
securitySettings.OwnerPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPassword"];
securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = true;
securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = false;
securitySettings.PermitPrint = true;
securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = false;
```

But if I do this then users cannot merge the PDF with another PDF. Password is asked while merging.

My question is: how can users merge the PDF without password but I want to apply security to PDF so that users don't edit the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You want to prevent modification, but you want to allow merging? AFAIK this cannot be done.

If users are able to merge files then they are also able to copy the file - and the copy would no longer be password protected and could be modified.

You cannot prevent modifications and at the same time allow merging (which is a modification).

Comment: from your answer seems to be there is no way to do that with PDFsharp.. can you suggest me another solution for implementing as i mentioned in my question.